# $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}x_j-\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j}x_i\not\equiv 0$ for harmonic homogeneous polynomials

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $p\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be an homogeneous polynomial with degree $d>0$, such that $\Delta p=0$, then $$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}x_j-\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j}x_i\not\equiv 0
$$
for at least one $i\neq j$.

It looks simple, but I am stucked at it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first notice that proving the statement for real polynomials implies the result in complex case. Thus, I assume that $p \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

The statement means that $\nabla p(x)$ and $x$ are not collinear everywhere. Arguing by contradiction, assume $\nabla p(x) \wedge x$ vanishes everywhere. But
$$0 = |\nabla p(x) \wedge x|^2 = \|\nabla p(x)\|^2\|x\|^2 - |\langle \nabla p(x), x \rangle|^2 = \|\nabla p(x)\|^2\|x\|^2 - d^2 |p(x)|^2$$
The last equality comes from the [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler%27s_theorem).
In other words, $|p(x)| = \frac{1}{d} \|\nabla p(x)\| \|x\|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. But $p$ is a non-constant harmonic function, thus $p$ cannot reach a local maximum. Hence, $p(x) = -\frac{1}{d}\|\nabla p(x)\| \|x\|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This is a contradiction with the fact that $p(0) = 0$ should be a global maximum.